# What is the difference between QByteArray and QList<unsigned char> or QVector<unsigned char>?

Tags: qt, qlist, qbytearray

`QByteArray` holds individual bytes, and if we make a `QList` of `unsigned chars` that will also hold the individual bytes.

What is the reason `QByteArray` exists when there can made a `QList<unsigned char>`?
What is the difference between `QByteArray` and `QList<unsigned char>` or `QVector<unsigned char>`?

What points am I missing?

Comment: 'QByteArray' is specialized on string operations, 'QList<T>' is not (replace, fromNumber, left/mid/right). so its like saying "why there is `std::string`when we could use `std::vector<char>`"

Comment: @Zaiborg could you please list out some major differences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QByteArray` is a usefull  wrapper around `char*`. Suitable for streaming with `QDataStream`, string operations and other data management.
From the docs you also can find that:

> Behind the scenes, it always ensures that the data is followed by a
>   '\0' terminator, and uses implicit sharing (copy-on-write) to reduce
>   memory usage and avoid needless copying of data.

`QList`, at first is not linear(subsequent) in memory (you should use `QVector`), and have no such usefull API

Comment: Does this all apply to QVector also?

Comment: @TheIndependentAquarius yes, the only major difference between list and vector is a memmory storage

Answer (score 1):

`QList` allocates memory on heap and does not guarantee any data locality, so there can be a performance difference between using `QList` and `QByteArray`.

From: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html#details

> QVector should be your default first choice. QVector will usually give better performance than QList, because QVector always stores its items sequentially in memory, where QList will allocate its items on the heap unless sizeof(T) <= sizeof(void*) and T has been declared to be either a Q_MOVABLE_TYPE or a Q_PRIMITIVE_TYPE using Q_DECLARE_TYPEINFO. See the Pros and Cons of Using QList for an explanation.

`QByteArray` also provides convenience methods for working with bytes (and strings in general).

Comment: `does not guarantee any data locality` Please explain this with reference to the qt's documents. Thanks.

Comment: `QVector should be your default first choice. QVector<T> will usually give better performance than QList<T>, because QVector<T> always stores its items sequentially in memory, where QList<T> will allocate its items on the heap unless sizeof(T) <= sizeof(void*) and T has been declared to be either a Q_MOVABLE_TYPE or a Q_PRIMITIVE_TYPE using Q_DECLARE_TYPEINFO. See the Pros and Cons of Using QList for an explanation.` - [QList](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html)

Comment: Thanks, in that case does it mean that `QVector <unsigned char>` will be same as `QByteArray`?